# The "Flag" modal keeps going down

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flag-dialog

When flagging a question or answer on stackoverflow.com or even meta.stackexchange.com and some other sites (didn't test more of them), each time the Flagging modal has to be re-rendered completely, it appears 59 pixels lower than the past one, causing it to slowly go away to the bottom of the page while navigating through its links.

Here's an image that explains it : [image: Clicking on links in the modal]

The easier way to reproduce it is by simply clicking successively between "Should be closed" and the "Flagging" breadcrumb link.

Comment: Repro-ed in Chrome/Win10

Comment: Hmm, thought this was only a Stack Overflow bug, but I'm seeing it here now. It has already been reported on MSO [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358609/6083675).

Comment: The issue is still there.

Comment: Fixed in the next build. Ilmari Karonen's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303611/115866) is spot on.

Comment: @balpha when will you finally recruit him? :)

Comment: @balpha When will that build go live? I currently still see it and after the new nav update it's a lot worse :(

Comment: @AndréKool I'm deploying this and a bunch of other fixes now, so it should be live in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that the `flag_showCloseDialog()` and `flag_showCloseDialog()` functions in `05_VoteToCloseAndFlag.js` (included in [full.en.js](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js)), which are responsible from switching from the flag popup to the close vote popup and back, are using jQuery [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead of [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) for determining the position of the old popup.  Thus, they end up determining the position of the popup *within the page* rather than *within the offset parent element*.  Then they use those values to set the CSS `top` and `left` properties of the new popup, which of course adjust the position of the new popup *relative to the offset parent*.

Presumably, this was not a problem in the past, since the offset parent of the popups (which are actually attached to the "flag" link in the DOM) used to be the whole page, or at least some element positioned at the top left corner of the page.  But with the new top bar redesign, the offset parent is now the `<div class="container">` element, which has a top margin of 40px to accommodate the top bar.

The obvious solution is to fix those two functions I mentioned above so that they'll call the right jQuery method.  I have tested this (using an ugly browser dev console hack) and can confirm that it indeed fixes the bug.  For SE devs' convenience, here's a ready-to-apply patch:

```
--- 05_VoteToCloseAndFlag.js    2017-11-24 09:05:36.381104431 +0200
+++ 05_VoteToCloseAndFlag_fixed.js  2017-11-24 09:06:25.465518105 +0200
@@ -236,7 +236,7 @@

     function close_pushFlaggingBreadcrumb() {
         close_pushTitleBreadcrumb("Flagging", function () {
-            var location = _closePopup.offset();
+            var location = _closePopup.position();

             if (!StackExchange.options.isMobile) {
                 _flagPopup.css({ top: location.top, left: location.left });
@@ -712,7 +712,7 @@
     };

     var flag_showCloseDialog = function (radioLoadClose) {
-        var location = _flagPopup.offset();
+        var location = _flagPopup.position();

         var deferred = _flagPopup.fadeOut('fast').promise();
```

Ps. As of v1.50, my [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script now contains [a fix for this bug](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/68cdb600b9a0e4901790585259216567ed548e33/SOUP.user.js#L1590).  It's basically the same as the "ugly browser dev console hack" I mentioned above, and works by monkey-patching jQuery's `.offset()` to act like `.position()` when called on the flag or close popups.