# Flag dialog jumps around

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flag-dialog

When I go through the flagging dialog it jumps to a different position. Steps to reproduce:

1. Click "flag" on my post.
2. Click "Should be closed."
3. Dialog Jumps to another position.
4. Click "Flagging" (in the top left corner)
5. Notice that the flag dialog jumps again.

This happens on all stack sites (tested here, [meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/))

As mentioned in the comments, this doesn't seem to happen with the close vote dialog.

[image: demo]

Comment: It's running away from our clicks. ;-)

Comment: Also worth to mention, this doesn't affect the close dialog, only flag dialog.

Comment: You can't flag me ;) (if you know the reference) :D

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Nope, that's a different issue. That was about the dialog "jumping" back to it's original position after you have moved it yourself.

Comment: ah, you're right

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yeah, this is a brand new bug. According to the class name of the dialog, probably part of making stuff responsive. ("responsively-horizontally-centered-legacy-popup" :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Actually, I'm pretty sure that this is the same bug as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303599/the-flag-modal-keeps-going-down. Not just because the symptoms are nearly identical, but also because the SOUP fix for that bug fixes this one too.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen agreed, missed that while searching. Voted to close as dupe.